# Request for member variables is something not a structure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Okay so I am creating a custom uitablviewcell in IB and the class I have created is called CustomCell
I have imported it in the header file and here is some code

```
 // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell =  (CustomCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

//errors start
cell.usernameText.text = [usernameArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.regionText.text = [regionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.gamesText.text = [gamesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.infoText.text = [aboutArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.concoleText.text = [concoleArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.micText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mic:%@",[MicArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

cell.ageText.text = [ageArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];   
  //till her
return cell;
}
```

why is there an error and what can i do to fix it.

Comment: Post code with `@interface CustomCell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you have class for your CustomCell(UITableViewCell)
>    and have the member usernameText, regionText, gamesText, infoText, concoleText, micText, and ageText of your CustomCell ? If no then you will get a warning *Request for member variables is something not a structure* because these are not the member variable. If you have not created separate class file for that then you may call cell.[textLabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).text = @"Welcome" textLabel is the member of UITableViewCell.

and you did not tell use what **ERROR** you were getting?

Comment: I have made a class class CustomCell and it has all the uilables

Comment: **What error you are getting** ? you should provide the error as well.

Comment: @TusharChutani show us the code for UITableViewCell ? you put the breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath method and check what kind of object it gets ?